# How to make an Angular Material <md-select> + UI Router view switcher?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-material

In a single page web app with [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), I'd like to make an [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/) `<md-select>` which will switch among several views (a.k.a. ui-router "states").

- In [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3pOQKRmuJRS7RyLbDP8) I am able to make that happen using plain `<select>` with [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), no Angular Material. Notice how the selected option of the `<select>` matches up with the location browsed to.
- In [this other plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwYRhgunssmGkdFkfG36) forked from the above appropriated with Angular Material, things don't work as nicely ☹ Upon browse (initial page load or URL click) the `<md-select>` does not get set to the initial location/state `<md-option>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [epelc](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3984#issuecomment-127123012) on Angular Material github:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="state in ctrl.$state.get()" ng-value="state.name">{{ state.name }}</md-option>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UqSwd3t1gRPfQdM5AMt6?p=preview)

Numyx's answer was very close, except it doesn't seem to be necessary to assign the JS object itself to `ng-value=""` as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `value` field of `md-option` to the state object instead of only the name (using `ng-value`) solved the problem:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="state in ctrl.$state.get()" ng-value="state">{{ state.name }}</md-option>
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LruC58BbWGWNeUiK54Kn?p=preview%20%22Updated%20Plunker)

Comment: OK this is showing some promising results! Just wondering about the `value=""` attribute which now contains `[object Object]`, is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Also, why does that work? Can you explain please; What does ng-value do in this case and how come it has this effect? Is this how it's documented, or do you happen to know some internal magics of angular, or something else?

Comment: To define the currently selected option the directive compares the `ng-model` value with the `value` fields of all options. This didn't work since the model was a state object but the value only a string, so the comparison always returns false. `ng-value` simply allows you to assign an object as value attribute. This is also the reason why you see the `[object Object]` as value attribute, the ng-value directive calls toString() on the value object and adds it as value field. But since the directive knows how to handle ng-value correctly, this is not really a problem.

Comment: OK I see. 1) The fact that ng-value allows you to assign an object as value attribute, is that documented officially? Can you show me where? 2) For someone pedantic who might want (or specifically need) `value` to be correct, what might be a way to achieve that?